# how to access specific and replace excel value of the data table C#

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable and want to access value in a specific row and then replace this value. I am able to access the first value in a column

```cs
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
            //DataTable table = new DataTable();
           DataTable table = tableCollection[cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    string value = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();

                    if (value.Equals("24"))
                    {
                        row["Column2"] = "25";
                    }
                    else if (value.Equals("AB"))
                    {
                        row["Column6"] = "November";
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: First you should probably debug and find out where things are going wrong... so check if `btnTest_Click` is even called, next check if `table.Rows` contains as many rows as you'd expect and  so on and so forth....
What library or package are you using to access your excel file?

Comment: Without knowing which library you are using, I find it unlikely that `row[col.ColumnName]` is a string. It might have a Value or something property that is a string.